# How to create a fair distribution algorithm?

Tags: normal-distribution, fair-division

I am even a math noob but need to understand what is the best mathematical formula for fair distribution. The problem statement is as follows:

We choose 2 numbers at a given time to distribute donations at a particular instance in time (The numbers from 1-6500 represent community members ID). The maximum % of the total resource we need to distribute between them is 10% from the overall resource pool. For fair distribution, we are counting the number of days they have served the community continuously. The longest one has served in days gets the appropriate amount of the distribution. I (Being very bad at mathematics come up with the following formula and hope no one will grill me for that :) ). Was looking for some expert to teach me how to come up with an algorithm for that:

```
            - Fd = Td * (Rn) * (Tp) /100
               Td  = Total number of days
               Rn  = Total Random numbers
               Tp  = Percentage of winning
```

Comment: So what are you trying to obtain? A recommended division of some prize between two people based on their days of community service?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: well then the number of community IDs shouldn't matter in that case if I understood correctly. Also, are they awarded based on total days of service or their longest streak of consecutive days of service?

Comment: The latter one. Longest streak of consecutive days of service

Comment: I need the output in percentile. Depending on their longest streak of consecutive days of service the percentage of prize distributed to them

Comment: Well I mean one possible division---and a very naive resolution--- is one where we award $(\frac{L_i}{L_1+L_2}\times 100)\quad\%$ of the prize to person $i$ where $L_i$ is the longest streak of service (in days) for person $i\in \{1,2\}$.  But ultimately, the validity of a "fair division" solution depends on how you define "fair."  Also, from a practical point of view, we may wonder whether the two people had the same time window and means to do service. Also, if you are only looking at longest streak, the above solution can give much more of the prize to someone who served far less.

Comment: For example, a person who worked 100 days only on every other day would have a max streak of one, whereas a person who worked just 9 days consecutively would have a max streak of 9; so in the resolution I mention, the first person would only get 10% of the prize.  If that is not "fair," then you have to use a different metric to define "fair."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132955/discussion-between-golden-ratio-and-ray).

Comment: I may have missed the question though---I certainly wouldn't characterize the solution I gave as a "fair division algorithm." "Fair division" often refers to far less trivial problems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_division

Comment: Hi, I would say that formula you gave would do. For my algo, the continuous days of service are very important. I guess (Li/L1+L2 * 100) works fine. Thanks alot :)

Comment: sure---no prob!